Add a numerical value to a variable while reading a file in bash in loop
I have a file with the following values. I am trying to read from the file and add 1096 to the last value and generate the output on screen. My original file looks like this.
agile_prod_toolkit,30
alsv2_prod_app,30
alsv2_qa_app,15

My expected output should be as below. the third value is second value + 1096
agile_prod_toolkit,30,1126
alsv2_prod_app,30,1126
alsv2_qa_app,15,1111

What i have tried is
while IFS="," read line ret;do
value=$ret+1095
print $line,$ret,$value
done < final_original

But this does not seem to work. can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?
The output that i am getting here when i run the above command is like this
agile_prod_toolkit,30,30+1095
alsv2_prod_app,30,30+1095
alsv2_qa_app,15,15+1095


What is the output you get?  You should edit your question to include it, to demonstrate the problem.

Apologies, i added the output now.

value=$ret+1095 is not an arithmetic assignment, and the bash shell has no print (perhaps you meant printf?).
You could do
while IFS=, read -r line ret; do 
  let value=$ret+1095
  echo "$line,$ret,$value"
done < final_original

or with the more modern arithmetic syntax and printf
while IFS=, read -r line ret; do 
  value=$((ret+1095))
  printf '%s,%d,%d\n' "$line" "$ret" "$value"
done < final_original

But really shells are not intended for text / arithmetic processing - consider using something like awk or miller instead:
awk -F, '{print $0 FS $NF+1095}' < final_original

mlr -N --csvlite put '$3 = $2 + 1095' < final_original


This worked. In future i will take the AWK route. I never taught about that before.
